# Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<Edge<T>>' to 'Edge<T>'

Tags: c#

I am using following code for getting first element of linkedlist worklist but i am getting error on line 2

> `Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<Edge<T>>' to 'Edge<T>'`

1. `LinkedList<Edge<T>> worklist = new LinkedList<Edge<T>>();`
2. `Edge<T> curr = worklist.First;`

according to definition of .First the above code should work. Please help me with this problem.

The definition of class Edge is given below

```
private sealed class Edge<T>
{

            public  T start;
            public  T end;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new edge between the two indicated endpoints.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start"> The edge's starting point. </param>
    /// <param name="end"> The edge's endpoint. </param>
    public Edge(T start, T end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
Edge<T> curr = worklist.First.Value;
```

`worklist.First` returns a `LinkedListNode<Edge<T>>`. You need to access the value of this first node in order to get an `Edge<T>`.

Comment: just need another help. I have two elements a and b of type T and i am trying to use if(a==b) but it says operator cannot be applied to operands of type T.

Comment: @user1210660 - What is the type? Did you constrain the generic type at all?

Comment: I haven't used c# before I am trying to convert code from java to c# and this comparison is allowed in java without any constraint. Please provide some solution or link to any tutorial for using generic type in c#. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1210660 - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx - I suggest using the `class` constraint.